# how to get Reporter.log error messages in background-red and font-white

Tags: html, selenium, testng

Right now I am using the code like 
    Reporter.log("NO ELEMENT      PRESENT in " + this.getClass() + " on "+ Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber() +": " + element + "");

I took a TestNG update ..and now it is showing error messages(White background and Black font) But I want Bachground=Red and Font-White..

Comment: <font color="FFFFFF" style="background-color:#FF0000">NO TEXT PRESENT in class C5.Banking.C5_Banking_PaymentSettings_Edit on 899: Process only on real update:</font>
Right now this is what Reporter.log output(It is displayed in White background and white black text font),When called by:
Reporter.log("<font color=\"FFFFFF\" style=\"background-color:#FF0000\">NO TEXT PRESENT in " + this.getClass() + " on "+ Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber() +": " + text + "</font>");

Comment: which report are you checking?

Comment: @niharika_neo I am checking the emailable-report.html (generated by TestNG under test-output folder.)

Comment: @Tarken can u please look into it.I have attached the code in first comment.